# Padding in Sass making Material UI icon disappear

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui, css-position

I am creating an image slider in React. I'm using Material UI arrow icons as the left and right buttons.

Everything is working fine until I try and add padding.

Before adding the padding, I can see two white circles with my arrows. As soon as I add the padding, the white circles get bigger but the arrows inside disappear.

```
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div
        className="slider"
        style={{ transform: `translateX(-${currentSlide * 100}vw)` }}
      >
        <img src={images[0]} alt="" />
        <img src={images[1]} alt="" />
        <img src={images[2]} alt="" />
        <img src={images[3]} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="arrows">
        <KeyboardArrowLeftOutlinedIcon className="arrow" onClick={prevSlide} />
        <KeyboardArrowRightOutlinedIcon className="arrow" onClick={nextSlide} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

And this is the sass file:

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

  .slider {
    width: 400vw;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    transition: all 1s ease;

    img {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }

  .arrows {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 80%;
    top: 0;

    .arrow {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 2em;
      padding: 1em;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a possible solution could be wrap the arrow icons with `div`, and style the wrapper.

Minimized demo of below example on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nphrjd?file=src/App.js) (without functionality, and uses plain CSS)

Example:

```
<div className="arrows">
  <div className="arrow">
    <KeyboardArrowLeftOutlinedIcon />
  </div>
  <div className="arrow">
    <KeyboardArrowRightOutlinedIcon />
  </div>
</div>
```

Also some changes in Sass would be needed to match it, such as:

```
.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
  .arrow {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2em;
    margin: 0.75em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```